# Is "intellectually exacerbating" grammatically correct; and does it mean what I think it means?

Tags: meaning

Is "intellectually exacerbating" grammatically correct, and does it mean something along the lines of "making others stupider"? If it doesn't, what adjective can I use in lieu of this phrase?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you add a sample sentence where you use it in a way you think is idiomatic? I can't see how you got that particular meaning.

Comment: It's too easy to mistake it for *exasperating.* And no, it doesn't mean that.

Comment: Maybe a search for synonyms of "stupefy" would give you some hints.

Comment: A phrase can be grammatically correct without being idiomatic or even making sense. _Exacerbate_ means to make a _problem_ worse, not to give someone less of a (good) quality.

Comment: How do you make someone stupid? You can make someone *seem* stupider by comparing them to someone else (including yourself).